# `test/dummy/config/application (LoadError)` when using `rails console` in a Rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-engines

After generating binstubs with `rails app:update:bin` post Rails 5 upgrade `rails console` now gives the error: `test/dummy/config/application (LoadError)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the generated code in `bin/rails` does not take in to account that RSpec is being used, which uses the `spec` directory, not `test`.

To fix open `bin/rails` and change the `APP_PATH` to point to the dummy app in the spec directory, i.e.

```
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../spec/dummy/config/application', __FILE__)
```